# Command rake db:schema:dump not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following `rake` command doesn't work

```
rake db:schema:dump
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:211: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `mysql`. I recommend installing a package manager such as [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), then doing a simple `brew install mysql`

Comment: where to install that package
in the same directory where i have installed my rails application?

Answer (score 2):

Your are probably missing something about a correct installation on osx and with a correct distribution of mysql libraries.
The fastest way of getting rid of this problem was a:

> $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

use the

> $ sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql-5.5.15-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

should be the proper solution

**Note:** Copied from [here](http://keybee.blogspot.in/2011/12/installing-rails-on-osx-with-mysql.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `mysql-client` and `libmysqlclient-dev` excepting your using a debian based linux. Anyway you need these libaries which are NOT part of the `mysql-server` package!

Answer (score 0):

In my case: Mountain Lion with mysql 5.5 and ruby 1.9.3 installed by RVM

The file libmysqlclient.18.dylib lives in

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.25a-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

I copied this file to "/usr/lib" folder and it fixed the error.

```
sudo cp /usr/local/mysql-5.5.25a-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/
```